# JQuery Sortable & Clone

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

I got stuck into problem since 2 days. Here we have drug and drop and we want to do clone items from right box to left. If i use draggable, it works, but all

droped items is no more possible to delete after drop ???

If i use both sortable, there is not posible to clone (sortible dont support clone) ???

How can i resolve this. is it bug or am i doing something wrong.
Gol is to have "read only" items in right side with possibility to drag and drop to left side and after to manipulate left list with sort and delete.
Tnx in advance

http://slusajonline.com/dragdrop7/untitled4.html

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, I would suggest since you are cloning the object you are losing the event handler for the delete button.

If you are using jQuery 1.3.2 then you can use:

```
$('.deleteButton').live('click',function( deleteIt() ))
```

rather than just

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function( deleteIt() ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a handy plugin for you.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

I guess your code does not look at the replaced or inserted objects, but only on those initially loaded.

Comment: This plugin is not needed if using jQuery 1.3.2